# Using UDP between remote server and client

Tags: sockets, networking, server, udp, real-time

I am currently working on a project that needs a UDP communication between a server Amazon Frankfurt) and several hosts (Arduino). I need to be able to send JSON data from server to a host over UDP and it needs to work in real time (time is a real constraint here). Also, periodically a host will speak to server to inform server about its status.

The problem I'm facing is that although I can ping the server, when I create the UDP socket with a port, I get this error (for any port):

> errno99: cannot assign requested address

I also believe that since the hosts are in different countries, I can only get router's IP. Hosts will be given to users therefore it is impossible to alter user's router by hand. I need to use something that can handle these by code.

I have been searching on **Hole Punching** and other techniques. I cannot decide what suits more to my scenario here. Sorry for my lack of network information, any help or guidance as "read or search these techniques" are appreciated.

This code runs on server:

```
 import socket
 import time
 #Host's public IP
 UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "178.243.98.86"
 UDP_PORT_NO = 13000
 Destination = (UDP_IP_ADDRESS,UDP_PORT_NO)
 Message = "Hello, Server"
 senderSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 while True:
     senderSock.sendto(Message, Destination)
     time.sleep(1);
```

And this code runs on my machine:

```
 import socket
 #Server's public IP
 UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "172.31.46.111"
 UDP_PORT_NO = 13000
 recieverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
 recieverSock.bind((UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))
 while True:
     data, addr = recieverSock.recvfrom(1024)
     print "Message: ", data
```

Comment: Also, you need to understand that UDP is a best-effort, fire-and-forget, connectionless protocol with no guaranteed delivery, and you _will_ lose some packets, so you need to take that into account. Real-time protocols that use UDP, like VoIP, take into account that packets go missing, and they take measures so that the effect on the application is minimized.

Comment: Could you please share the code and the whole stack trace? Being unable to bind to an IP and port has nothing to do with NAT issues. You will certainly meet the latter (unless you work in IPv6 and simply don't have NAT), but the former is another thing.

Comment: @RonMaupin It will be an emergency warning system, that's why I need to work on real time. I will send the same data several times to restore if a packet is missing.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 I tried to use the simple  server client example like at  [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) with using public IPs. However I have not tried to use hole punching because as I understand from what I read, before sending any packets there should be a live connection between host and server. Since my project is an emergency warning system, I may need to send the warning any undetermined time

Comment: "_I will send the same data several times to restore if a packet is missing._" I 'm not sure that TCP would not be more appropriate. It would guarantee data delivery, in the proper order. A real-time system would understand that missing data happens, deal with the fact that it doesn't have all the data, and move on. Requesting that missing data be resent is not real-time behavior.

Comment: We have no evidence you didn't make a mistake adapting the code for your application, this is why including the code is important. At minimum you don't need to bind socket to a particular address or port at a client side. But I can't come up with something more detailed unless I see what exactly has been written.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 Thank you for your help, I have updated the question with the code I tried to run. I have check my host's ip using http://ipinfo.io/ip website. However, I get the same IP for other devices on the same LAN like my phone, I guess it is the router's . This is one of the obstacles I could not get over.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thank you for comment, actually think the data I will send as a boolean, "warning : true" or not. The thing is this project will be able to work with many devices as an emergency warning system, therefore, 3-way handshake with each device can reduce the speed of warning system which is the core of the project. That's why I decided to use UDP.

Answer (score 0):

### Server

```
# Host's public IP
UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "178.243.98.86"
```

You cannot rely on `178.243.98.86`. Your arduinos are behind one or several NATs. With NAT, when a packet leaves a network, your packets source and/or destination addresses (and most likely ports) get rewritten. When this conversion happens, a device responsible for NAT remembers this conversion, but only for a *limited period of time*. The period usually defaults to 24h.

In order to overcome this issue, it's up to clients to initiate conversations with the server. Introduce a new message type to your protocol saying something like `hey it's me, client #34`. The server should be associating source IP and port of the received message with client #34 for some period of time, like hours.

In this case the server binds a socket to an address and port as well as a client. And beware that `hey it's me, client #34` sent over UDP is not encrypted and is extremely vulnerable to record and replay attacks. I believe an emergency system should be encrypted.

### Client

```
# Server's public IP
UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "172.31.46.111"
```

`172.31.46.111` cannot be server's public IP, because it is an address from [an IPv4 private space](https://www.arin.net/knowledge/address_filters.html). You probably meant to say "host's private address". It makes sense to bind to such an address. You get an error most likely because you have incorrectly determined the IP address of your host.

There are several ways to get the correct IP. If you use DHCP (you use it if you've never though about what IPs to use in your SOHO), log into your nearest router's admin interface and check the *DCHP Pool*. Alternatively, Linux and Windows have terminal commands to do the same. For Arduino, you have probably assigned it a static address. If so, bind to it.

Answer (score 0):

You also seem to open a tcp socket on the server, and connect to it from client via udp socket. Is this intentional?

- gsn

Comment: This should be in the comments section as it is not an answer.